# Htaccess mod rewrite don't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, phalcon

I have a project with two applications: a frontend (in AngularJs) and a backend (in Phalcon). I my server document root i have two folders and one htaccess:

```
public_html
 - api
     - controllers
     - index.php
 - app
 - .htaccess
```

The .htaccess have the next configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ api/index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

So, when i send a POST request (for example) to `http://mydomain/api/sessions`, the result is 404 not found. The router configuration is:

```
$router->addPost('/sessions', array(
    'controller' => 'sessions',
    'action' => 'post'
));
```

In my localhost works fine with this configuration. But, in my VPS not. 
Any ideas ?

**Update 1:**

If i don't use any REST service, accessing via `http://mydomain/api` the Phalcon index controller is loaded.

**Update 2:**

If i try to access a REST service using a Phalcon url like `http://mydomain/api/index.php?_url=/licenses` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the problem. the virtual host configuration file had not the next lines:

```
<Directory "/var/www/domain/public_html">
   Options All
   AllowOverride All
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Ah, so the .htaccess file wasn't being processed at all? So, requesting `http://mydomain/api/sessions` directly in the browser would have also resulted in a 404 I assume. A request for `http://mydomain/api` wouldn't match the `RewriteRule` anyway so would have simply loaded `http://mydomain/api/index.php` (on Apache with the appropriate options).

Answer (score 1):

You can sometimes get away with relative path substitutions in the document root, however, you should make the `RewriteRule` substitution root-relative (starts with a slash), or specify a `RewriteBase /` directive after you enable the rewrite engine in order to explicitly specify the URL prefix.

> RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ api/index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]

Becomes:

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /api/index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What if you do a GET request in the browser?